# Installing WAMP and WordPress: Visual Studio 2013 or 2012?

Tags: installation

I am following the Lynda.com tutorial for installing and running WordPress with WAMP. In order to download WAMP, it says I must have Visual Studio 2012: VC 11 vcredist_x64 / x86.exe. This computer does have Visual Studio 2013 already installed, will this suffice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Visual studio is a code editor, WAMP is the actual software that runs a web server so that you can view the website on your computer without having to upload the files to a server, they are not connected.  The tutorial likely just wants you to have a decent code editor first, but having visual studio is not a requirement for downloading or using WAMP in any way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install and run WordPress, you don't need Visual Studio at all. You will probably need some code editor later, if you want to create/modify some theme files etc.